# Geometry Nodes Images as Planes, Instance on Points always face camera

Tags: geometry-nodes, camera

I have a wide scene with Geometry Nodes distributing Images as Planes across my entire scene, how can I ensure all the planes are facing the camera and/or does it matter?  I am noticing come color differences across the scene which could by lighting but I am thinking it could also be that the planes are not all facing the camera due to my wide angle focal length.  I'd at least like to learn/try and see what happens if I can tell blender to ensure the distributed objects are 'facing' my cameras sensor.  I have already aligned the planes to the front of my camera, maybe that's enough?  I found a thread to do this with a Particle Systems but I have GNs